# Vertical space introduced by ctex?

Tags: vertical-spacing, ctex

I have to use ctex package for typing Chinese, but it comes annoying extra space between section and equations. I tried many commands but cannot remove this space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\Large
\chapter{Introduction}
This is an introduction.
\section{Basic concept}

{\color{blue} \boldmath
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&B+C=180^{\circ}, \\
&A+D+E=360^{\circ}
\end{aligned}  \tag{T1}
\end{equation}  }

Above equations show ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

Can someone help me to remove this space?

My equations seems somehow strange, I want to use bold font in whole questions, I cannot find a better solution. But it doesn't influence above vertical space.

Comment: By default, `ctex` sets line spread to 1.3 (`scheme=chines`). Try `\usepackage[scheme=plain]{ctex}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ yes, your suggestion works, thanks. But I find another package indentfirst would enlarge the space as well, do you have good ideas?

Comment: note that there should never be a blank line before equations really, the spacing  is never great in that case anyway. By luck (mostly) after a section heading that suppresses indentation you will also suppress the spurious white  paragraph before an equation, but if you disable that you will get the same bad spacing that you get in other cases not immediately after a section head.

Comment: @John If you do not need the indent-every-paragraph effect, then you do not need `indentfirst` package.